# Python3 installed using homebrew but not updated version being used

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, installation, homebrew

On my Mac terminal i've installed python3 (3.7.6) using homebrew - e.g. if I issue command to upgrade via homebrew, it returns the up to date version:

```
$brew upgrade python3
Warning: python3 3.7.6_1 already installed
```

However when I ask for the version it tells me an older version (3.4.0) is installed:

```
$python3 --version
Python 3.4.0
```

So it's installed but not updated. I'd quite like 3.6 or later on my mac. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling using homebrew, and had no luck. Wondering if anyone has any ideas?

//

Sidenote (1) - i'm relatively new to homebrew... `$ brew doctor` returns config scripts "outside your system or Homebrew directories" - not sure if this helps, and if this is the issue where to move them to.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4m-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4-config
```

Sidenote (2) - 3.7.6 isn't the newest version out, but this is the latest version that homebrew will install. Is there any way to get an even newer version?

Answer (score 2):

By chance i've come across the/a answer. I was editing `.bash_profile` and saw the very top says:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

So I moved to this directory ...`/Versions/`, found it had three subdirectories 3.3, 3.4, and 3.8, and updated to use:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
```

And this seems to do the trick (to use the most recent). Although interestingly i've not came across 3.7.6... but is a bit redundant in my case since I can use the newer 3.8 version.

Comment: For me the solution was to simply delete this two lines from the .profile.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick fix:**

You should be able to run the required version by running *python3.7* instead of *python3*. You can set up an alias if you like with

"alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7"

where you put the desired binary on the RHS. This will create an alias for your current session. To always evoke this functionality, you can add this line to your bashrc file so this alias will work every time you log in to a new session

echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7" >> ~/.bashrc

These commands were lifted from 
https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac
which explains some do and do-nots.

**Alternative:**

Also check out Python virtual environments, particularly *virtualenv* and *virtualenvwrapper*, which are great tools for separating out your Python working environments and allow you to set default Python version for each project separately, as well as managing any modules you pip install separately for each project. This is much cleaner in my opinion.

https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_virtualenv_virtualenvwrapper.php

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful. I've just posted that i've come across an answer by changing the path in .bash_profile, which hadn't been updated. But your response is also really useful and i'll check out the Python virtual environments for sure!